# Chap stick Flavored Kashrut

Tags: kashrut-kosher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [kashrus of mouthwash, toothpaste, lip balm](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/kashrus-of-mouthwash-toothpaste-lip-balm)

What's the Kashrus status of the flavored Chapsticks? Are they allowed or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [OK's position](http://www.kosherspirit.com/Article.asp?Issue=11&Article=123) is that even if some of it is consumed it is not *derech achila* (normal way of eating) so it does not need a *hechsher*.