# Does flavored dental floss need a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, teeth

You can find flavored dental floss these days usually in the flavor of mint.
Is there anything to worry about or is it no worse than mint mouthwash?

If not, doesn't the gemarah in berachot 6th perek say that it's assur to taste anything without a beracha?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/kashrus-of-mouthwash-toothpaste-lip-balm

Comment: @IsaacMoses Why not just edit "floss" into that question? The answers discuss it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [CRC-Chicago](https://twitter.com/crckosher/status/21942742661)

> All dental floss, including flavored, may be used. However, during
>   pesach one should only use the unflavored variety.