# Are Colgate wisps allowed?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, medicine, hechsher-certification, cleaning, teeth

I am basing my question based off a question asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/kashrus-of-mouthwash-toothpaste-lip-balm).

It seems like from there the general consensus seems that toothpaste does not have to be kosher. The way the wisp works is that it is a mini disposable silicon toothbrush that has a little ball with cleaning ingredients in the center of the brush to clean the teeth [(see here)](https://www.target.com/p/colgate-max-fresh-wisp-disposable-mini-toothbrush-peppermint-24ct/-/A-14886128). There are two issues that Colgate wisps that may differentiate them from toothpaste:

1. It is rinse free, so you are likely going to "consume" the entire ball.
2. The third ingredient is gelatin, which they say is directly from pork.

Comment: To those wanting to close, seems to me this is not a request for personal psak but rather an interesting question as to the kosher status of a new product. Answers might include which Rav or certification institution found the product to be (or not) kosher

Comment: https://thelakewoodscoop.com/news/kashrus-alert-popular-colgate-item-contains-gelatin-derived-from-pork/

Comment: Gelatin from pork is a non-issue according to some (e.g. R. Haim Ozer, R. Abadi, et al).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Colgate's Consumer Affairs Representative says:

[image]

Comment: Well, that seems to answer the question :) Good Shabbos!

Comment: Did you receive this email? How do we know it's genuine?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question because we know that toothpaste doesn't need to be kosher. I already stated that it contains pork.

Comment: Since when is Colgate a halachic authority?

Comment: @shmosel agreed. It would have been more accurate of them to say "is not certified as kosher". There are authorities that might not take issue with a pork derived component.

Comment: @DoubleAA I have no reason to doubt the genuineness of this email, and is in line by what was reported here: https://thelakewoodscoop.com/news/kashrus-alert-popular-colgate-item-contains-gelatin-derived-from-pork/ (hat tip @Shmuel)

Comment: @Seeker Your question said: *"The third ingredient is gelatin, which **they say** is directly from pork."* Who is "they say"? I answered that the company said it themself ("they are made from pork"). They also said that it contains "pork products" (in the plural form).

Comment: @Seeker Who is "we know"? I received a direct psak from two rabbanim in kashrus to check my toothpaste to make sure it did not have animal-derived glycerin.

Comment: @N.T. I was basing it off of a different thread, I attached the link to it in my question.

Comment: @IsraelReader and Shmuel, Happens to be I saw that email and that is exactly why I posted my question - because I saw in the thread that I linked to that toothpaste doesn't need to be kosher (at least that is the general consensus of that thread). That email is the cause of my question - not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Atlanta Kosher Commission (via [Kosherquest](https://kosherquest.org/from-the-akc-atlanta-kosher-commission-colgate-disposable-toothbrushes/)) puts them as not recommended.

(In my personal experience, two rabbanim involved with kashrus told me to check toothpaste with glycerin as an ingredient to make sure it is not produced from animals.)

Comment: According to this link: https://thelakewoodscoop.com/news/kashrus-alert-popular-colgate-item-contains-gelatin-derived-from-pork/ Colgate claims that "All glycerin used in our toothpastes comes from only synthetic or vegetable sources".

Comment: @IsraelReader I was using a more specialty brand at the time.